# Finding the value of $x+y$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]

$x^3+y^3=(x+y)(x^2-xy+y^2)=400$

and for

$x^2y+xy^2=(x+y)(x^2+y^2)=200$

I decided to multiply by $2$ on both sides: $(x+y)(x^2+y^2)=200$ or $2(x+y)(x^2+y^2)=2(200)$

So then I set the equations equal to each other:

$2(x+y)(x^2+y^2)=(x+y)(x^2-xy+y^2)=400$

I am having trouble solving though because there is two variables involved. Any ideas?

Comment: Note that $x^2y+xy^2\ne (x+y)(x^2+y^2)$.

Comment: $x+y=\sqrt[3]{x^3+y^3+3\left(x^2y+xy^2\right)}$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $(x+y)^3=x^3+3x^2y+3xy^2+y^3=x^3+y^3+3xy(x+y)$.

Comment: You don't need the last equality. $x+y=\sqrt[3]{x^3+y^3+3\left(x^2y+xy^2\right)}$.

Comment: I was explaining the key fact, in terms of a perhaps familiar expansion.

Comment: however, how can i introduce the $3$ since the above equations don't have them and if i multiply the 2nd equation by $2$, well...thats just not $3$

Comment: $x^3+y^3=400$, and $xy(x+y)=200$ (given). So $3xy(x+y)=600$. By the identity of the hint, $(x+y)^3=400+600=1000$. So $x+y=\sqrt[3]{1000}=10$.